# "Performing VCS refresh" to slow in PhpStorm using TFS plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PhpStorm and the Visual Studio Team Services Plugin, sometimes when I try to check-in some file appears the "Performing VCS refresh" window and it remains for a very long time...

In the attachments there's a log file, but I can't understand what is the problem... some help?

[log file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-intellij/files/1639301/idea.log)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the plugin action Tfs.ItemInfo is executing some unexpected calls. Please [report the issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-intellij/issues) to the plugin vendor.

You could also collect a [thread dump using jstack](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899) to see what exactly IDE is doing behind the Performing VCS refresh action.